# Extreme Value Theorem on an Unbounded Domain

Tags: real-analysis, smooth-functions, extreme-value-theorem, extreme-value-analysis

Given a *smooth* function  $f(x)\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $. Suppose $$\lim_{x\to -\infty} f(x) = 0, $$ and 
$$ \lim_{x\to \infty} f(x) = 0. $$
Can we claim that $f$ is bounded?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: Turn this "picture" into a proof

If $x$ is sufficiently large, say $x>M$ then $f(x)$ is small.

If $x$ is sufficiently small, say $x<-N$ then $f(x)$ is small.

The interval $[-N,M]$ is closed, $f$ is continuous and therefore $f$ is bounded on this interval.

So it's either small, or bounded, or small. Therefore it is bounded.

Now make this formal

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot!